# Return nil vs zero length string

Tags: objective-c

Being fairly new to Objective-C, I find myself often torn between whether a method that returns an `NSString` should return an empty string, or return a `nil`, and I'm not sure what standard practice is, but it appears in Objective-C that much of the language is built around properly handling nils.

For example, I have a `NSManagedObject` category method that returns a guid (if the managed object has a guid field).

```
-(NSString*)guidValue {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(guid)]) {
        return [self guid];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

So in my final return statement, should I do the Objective-C standard and `return nil;` or is it just an arbitrary subjective decision and `return @"";` is just as valid from a standards point of view.

Comment: @LogicsaurusRex also, there is no reason to use `valueForKey:` with a constant key.   Instead, just call the method directly, thereby reducing a slight bit of overhead and, **far more importantly** allowing the compiler to typecheck the code and complain if some future refactor might break things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nil` is the better choice since it indicates that there is no value. The empty string could be a valid return value (maybe not in this specific case but in others).

It really depends on whether you need to differentiate between no value (`nil`) and a real value (the empty string).

By returning `nil` to indicate "no value", the calling code can make an appropriate decision:

```
NSString *guid = [someObject guidValue];
if (guid) {
    // use the guid as needed
} else {
    // uh-oh - no guid - do something else as needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on how you've designed your application to work, and how this method is to be used.

As a general rule, a `nil` would make more logical sense than an empty string.

For eg., say you're validating a guid as in:

```
if ([managedObject guid]) {
    NSLog(@"success");
}
```

A design based on nil would work better.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the intention. An empty string is not the same as `nil`, because `nil` means there's no string at all.

Despite built-in handling of `nil`s in Objective-C, you could use `nil` as an extra state of a field or property, indicating an "unknown value".